# map() returns value pairs with object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have object like picture below.

[image]

I want to use `map()` to retrieve the object like

```
{
  "2643216":{pg:1,pt:1},
  "1304681":{pg:1,pt:1}
}
```

Here is my code.

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function(x){
                return {obj[x].number:{'pg':obj[x].pg,'pt':obj[x].pt}}
                })
```

But errors may appear at the `obj[x].number`.

The debug errors notifies me the ignorance of the `: (colon)`.

Is there mistake I make and any adjustment you can suggest-

or other way can retrieve the object I want?

Thank you.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: `{obj[x].number:{'pg':obj[x].pg,'pt':obj[x].pt}}` this is not valid JS syntax

Comment: It seems that you're missing the colon (":") here: "2643216"{pg:1,pt:1} - just before the "{". Have you fixed it?

Comment: Thaks for everyone helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job:

```js
function groupByNumber(data) {

  return Object
    .keys(data)
    .reduce(function(result, key) {
      var value = data[key];

      result[value.number] = { pt: value.pt, pg: value.pg };

      return result;
    }, {});
};

var data = {
  'LKB_something': { number: 1, pg: 1, pt: 5 },
  'LKB_something_else': { number: 2, pg: 1, pt: 5 },
  'LKB_something_else_1': { number: 3, pg: 1, pt: 5 },
};

console.log('result', groupByNumber(data));
```

---

```
// ES-NEXT would let you be more coincise
const groupByNumber = data => Object.values(data).reduce(
  (result, { number, ...rest }) => ({ ...result, [number]: rest }),
  {},
);
```

Comment: but explain why NOT to use `.map()` ?

Comment: `map` cannot return a value like:  `{ "2643216"{pg:1,pt:1}, "1304681":{pg:1,pt:1} }`

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic key in a JavaScript object, you need square brackets to make a computed property name:

```
return { [obj[x].number]: { "pg": obj[x].pg, "pt": obj[x].pt }}
```

And your code could be simplified using `Object.values` and the implicit return of an arrow function, along with destructuring and shorthand property notation, like so:

```
Object.values(obj).map(({ number, pg, pt }) => ({ [number]: { pg, pt }}))
```

Note that the above returns an array of objects - if you want an object:

```
Object.values(obj).reduce((a, { number, pg, pt }) => ({ ...a, [number]: { pg, pt }}), {})
```

Comment: Because I use google app script,it only supplies Object.keys  and does not support Object.values.

Comment: [obj[x].number] cannot use.It's maybe an invaid syntax.